# Wordpress reporting the wrong registration date/time

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm tracking when users register through my wordpress site. In order to store the user information, I have the following code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if (is_user_logged_in() && $user) {
  $identify = array(
    'user_id' => $user->user_email,
    'traits'  => array(
      'username'  => $user->user_login,
      'email'     => $user->user_email,
      'name'      => $user->display_name,
      'firstName' => $user->user_firstname,
      'lastName'  => $user->user_lastname,
      'url'       => $user->user_url,
      'created_at' => $user->user_registered
    )
  );
}
```

However `$user->user_registered` is somehow reporting a unix timestamp that's 7 hours ahead. I logged into my server and it showed the current time accurately. I went to my general settings and my time zone is 7 hours behind. However a unixtimestamp should be consistent no matter the time zone, no? So my question is this: why is user_registered showing the incorrect unix time and how can I fix it?

Comment: php has it's own timezone setting that is set in php.ini. Check a phpinfo page or just create a simple page that calls `date('d-M-Y H:i:s')`

Comment: Check your WordPress time zone settings under settings->general->timezone.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn & JayBhatt isn't a unixtimestamp always consistent?

Comment: @NickONeill No. It depends on your local settings and the way you generate your timestamp. Also WordPress can override your system local and in that case the timestamp will be different.

Comment: @NickONeill see these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184192/php-mysql-converting-stored-timestamp-into-users-local-timezone

Comment: Typically yes, a unix timestamp is consistent. However, when converted to a date, it is adjusted for your timezone settings.

Comment: @NickONeill http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029766/showing-mysql-timestamps-in-local-time

Comment: @JayBhatt `localtime` doesn't seem to work